# PHP script not running in CLI

Tags: php, windows, syntax-error, command-line-interface

First question here. I’m new to (php) programming, but stackoverflow has already helped me with a lot. Unfortunately I wasn’t able to (quickly enough) find a solution to this:

I’ve made a loop that checks the content on a webpage every few seconds and writes it to a database, and with EasyPHP and firefox it works; it just times out after 30 seconds. But I have problems getting it to work in CLI (windows 7). The environment variables and registry are set up correctly, as far as I can tell. I have the php.ini from the CGI-php in the same folder as the file I want to run. 
So when I try to run it with CMD (cd to folder -> `php <file.php>`) I get a wide variety of warnings and notices, what I can see are: timezone warnings about strtotime, undefined variable: lastdate (line 58), file_get_contents: failed to open stream (line 23), could not find driverPHP, undefined variable: sql (line 12), unable to find the wrapper "https" (line 23), while "-l" says everything is OK.

I have no idea of what I’m doing wrong here, or if I have PHP installed incorrectly or if it’s something else?

**EDIT:** changed the question now I realize I cant load php.ini as a php file..

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "newdb";
$tablename = "test1";
$maxinterval = 10;
$mininterval = 2;
$loophandle = fopen("loopcheck.txt", "r");

    function seconds2human($ss) { //taken from somewhere via stackoverflow.com
$s = $ss%60;
$m = floor(($ss%3600)/60);
$h = floor(($ss%86400)/3600);
$d = floor(($ss%2592000)/86400);
$M = floor($ss/2592000);

return "$M months, $d days, $h hours, $m minutes, $s seconds";
}

    function GetJsonFeed($json_url) //taken from somewhere on bitcointalk.org
{
    $feed = file_get_contents($json_url);
    return json_decode($feed, true);
}

fread($loophandle, 25);
while ($loopcheck = true){  //start loop, $loopcheck is in loopcheck.txt
    fread($loophandle, 25); 

$ltc_btc = GetJsonFeed("https://btc-e.com/api/3/ticker/ltc_btc"); //update server data to array
$ltc_btc_high = $ltc_btc["ltc_btc"]["high"];
$ltc_btc_low = $ltc_btc["ltc_btc"]["low"];
$ltc_btc_avg = $ltc_btc["ltc_btc"]["avg"];
$ltc_btc_vol = $ltc_btc["ltc_btc"]["vol"];
$ltc_btc_vol_cur = $ltc_btc["ltc_btc"]["vol_cur"];
$ltc_btc_last = $ltc_btc["ltc_btc"]["last"];
$ltc_btc_buy = $ltc_btc["ltc_btc"]["buy"];
$ltc_btc_sell = $ltc_btc["ltc_btc"]["sell"];
$ltc_btc_updated = $ltc_btc["ltc_btc"]["updated"];

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM test1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if($result !== false) {
            foreach($result as $row) {
            $lastdate = $row['timestamp']; //retreive last table entry timestamp
            }
        }
    $conn = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
$currdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$diff = abs(strtotime($currdate) - strtotime($lastdate)); //determine last table entry age
    if($diff >= $maxinterval){
        include "lastchecktime.txt";
        $diff2 = abs(strtotime($currdate) - strtotime($lastchecktime));
        if(seconds2human($diff2) < $mininterval){
            $lastchecktime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $writetxt='$lastchecktime=';
            fwrite(fopen("lastchecktime.txt", "w+"), "<?php $writetxt '$lastchecktime' ?>");
            fclose(fopen("lastchecktime.txt", "r"));
            include 'Insert apidata2.php';
        }
    }
}
fclose($loophandle);
?>
```

And the referenced "Insert apidata2.php" file:

```
<?php

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tablename (high, low, avg, vol, vol_cur, last, buy, sell, updated)
    VALUES ('$ltc_btc_high','$ltc_btc_low','$ltc_btc_avg','$ltc_btc_vol','$ltc_btc_vol_cur','$ltc_btc_last','$ltc_btc_buy','$ltc_btc_sell','$ltc_btc_updated')";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;

?>
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of `file.php`?

Comment: You're basically telling us that you're getting some errors while running some code. We'll probably only be able to really help you if you can specify what the errors are, and what the code is. (Also, if you want to write stuff with angle brackets in questions, comments or answers here, try wrapping it in backticks; that'll stop it being interpreted as HTML and disappearing. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: I'm curious as to what you're trying to do with the `php -c <file.php>`. [The `-c` option specifies a particular INI file](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) to use, so your syntax error is because you're providing a PHP file, not an INI file.

Comment: Code added. Ok Matt thanks! 
If i run it with "php -c <file.php>" using the config.ini is also use with EasyPHP I get the error I described. Nothing more to it. Without the "-c" it gives timezone warnings about strtotime, undefined variable: lastdate (line 58), file_get_contents: failed to open stream (line 23), could not find driverPHP, undefiend variable: sql (line 12), unable to find the wrapper "https" (line 23). Thats all I can see.

Comment: I thought that if I left added nothing directly after '-c' it would find the file in the opened folder. But using it correctly gives the same errors from my earlier comment. Thanks for pointing that out though!

Comment: There's nothing too scary to worry about here. You'll often find that your php.ini file needs fixing with a new install, and errors about timezones, etc., are pretty common. (Hint: edit your php.ini so that it has a timezone. When in doubt, `date.timezone = UTC`.) Show us the errors that are appearing, and we'll solve them, one by one. It's quite possible that the PHP files served by your web server are (silently) complaining about just the same problems... It can be a tad challenging to figure out which php.ini is being used for which invocation of PHP, but it's worth figuring out.

Comment: I was able to solve this. Turns out CMD was using a different PHP installation than I had intended, it's php.ini didn't have all the proper extensions enabled and their paths were set to /php/ instead of php/ext/. Thanks for bearing with me @MattGibson